# changing the font size dynamically

Tags: fontsize

For my document I have some commands that write a bit of text in a different font-size. This works fine until I want to set this text as subscript. The text generated by my command then has the same absolute size in both cases (as expected).
Is there a way to modify my command in a way that it changes the size according to whether it is in normal script or subscript? I could have different commands for subscript and normal but then I would have to find adequate sizes for the subscript and my commands list would blow up even more.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mytext}[0]{\text{\normalsize{World}}}
\begin{document}
    IS:\\
    Normal: Hello $\mytext$\\
    Subscript: Hello $_\mytext$\\
    \par
    WANT:\\
    Normal: Hello World\\
    Subscript: Hello $_\text{World}$
\end{document}
```

[image]
Obviously, I don't actually use `\normalsize` but e.g. `\footnotesize`, `\small`, etc.

Comment: There is the [relsize](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/relsize/relsize-doc.pdf) package that provides the commands `\larger` and `\smaller`, which are relative to the current size.

Comment: thx, that's it. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: Done. As an unrelated comment: your use of `\normalsize{argument}` is incorrect, `\normalsize` is a switch that does not take arguments. It has local scope in a group (here the scope is the `\text` command) so you don't get any side effects in this particular case, but what happens is that `\normalsize` changes the font size for everything inside the scope and `{}` is ignored. So correct is `{\normalsize World}` which explicitly sets the scope _around_ the switch and does not use arguments.

Comment: true, I forgot that in the MWE, but thx for point that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [relsize](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/relsize/relsize-doc.pdf) package defines relative size commands. The main command is `\relsize{n}` with `n` positive or negative for larger and smaller text, respectively. There are also shortcut commands `\larger` and `\smaller` for `\relsize{1}` and `\relsize{-1}`.

To replicate the MWE the main command can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mytext}[0]{\text{\relsize{0}World}}
\newcommand{\mysmalltext}[0]{\text{\relsize{-1}World}}
\begin{document}
    IS:\\
    Normal: Hello $\mytext$\\
    Subscript: Hello $_\mytext$\\
    \par
    WANT:\\
    Normal: Hello World\\
    Subscript: Hello $_\text{World}$\\
    \par
    IS:\\
    Normal: Hello $\mysmalltext$\\
    Subscript: Hello $_\mysmalltext$\\
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]